# How to debug print the flow of the executable of the 3rd party

Tags: c#, .net

I have a third party library(Assembly) used in the project.  I want to know if there is a way to print out all its method entry information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely need to use reflection if you want to do this programmatically: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)

Otherwise, you could try disassembling the library with [Red Gate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

### Edit:

Reflection does not allow you to change anything about the methods. If you are wanting to print out the methods as you originally asked, you can retrieve:

1. Method name
2. Method return type (void, or otherwise)
3. Method parameters and return types

The only way you would be able to *change* (or `override`) a method is if the method is defined as `virtual`. You can determine if a method is overrideable through reflection as well: [MethodBase.IsVirtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isvirtual.aspx).

Comment: Yes. I want to do it pro grammatically.  You mean I can reflect the method and change the method ontime by using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly dependent on how much has been exposed by the 3rd party. As dboarman suggested, you can use reflection [or the Reflector tool].

You can also use Debug View. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Using DebugView, you can get a bunch of text that the 3rd party may [or may not] have written. Mostly good developers instrument the code.

Comment: I have been using DebugView for about 6 months - I don't know how I got along without it.